# Redis socket exception

Tags: performance, sockets, redis, timeout, load-testing

org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_292]

at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[?:1.8.0_292]

at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[?:1.8.0_292]

at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[?:1.8.0_292]

at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[?:1.8.0_292]

at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607) ~[?:1.8.0_292]

at redis.clients.jedis.DefaultJedisSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultJedisSocketFactory.java:53) ~[jedis-3.3.0.jar:?]

at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:158) ~[jedis-3.3.0.jar:?]

at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:109) ~[jedis-3.3.0.jar:?]

at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:1904) ~[jedis-3.3.0.jar:?]

at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:130) ~[jedis-3.3.0.jar:?]

at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:868) ~[commons-pool2-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]

at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:435) ~[commons-pool2-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]

at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363) ~[commons-pool2-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]

at redis.clients.jedis.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:50) ~[jedis-3.3.0.jar:?]

at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:288) ~[jedis-3.3.0.jar:?]

at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:15) ~[jedis-3.3.0.jar:?]

at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:271) ~[spring-data-redis-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]

On high load application are frequently getting timeout issues with Redis

Comment: It's nice that you posted the answer you found yourself, however, you seem to give more details on your answer than on your question. This question only provides an error message, giving more context to the error usually helps with getting an answer (SO/machine you have the program installed, version of the program and java in this case as it relies in java for execution... that type of details)

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

1. verified CPU utilization of redis, it's hitting spike sometimes
2. connected to redis-cli
   3.redis-cli --latency  - to get the idea of what is latency.
3. SLOWLOG GET after connecting to redis-cli

river@host:~$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> SLOWLOG GET

1. 1. (integer) 147089
   2. (integer) 1679571368
   3. (integer) 851347
   4. 1. "HGETALL"
      2. "\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\x10Profile"
   5. ---
   6. ""
2. 1. (integer) 147088
   2. (integer) 1679571367
   3. (integer) 844762
   4. 1. "HGETALL"
      2. "\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\x10Profile"
   5. ---
   6. ""
3. 1. (integer) 147087
   2. (integer) 1679571366
   3. (integer) 851313
   4. 1. "HGETALL"
      2. "\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\x10Profile"
   5. ""
4. 1. (integer) 14708

Based above response I got to  know this is causing an issue, verified in the application from where it's getting triggered
Fixed it from caller end

Problem solved.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how did you fix it?